# How to Map this Array of objects to get a full object by deffrient specfic code property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Hey I need to map this array of products. I want to get the full objects after search with a specific value of the `code` property.

For example, how do I find all objects where the `code` is `"balance"`?

```js
"products": [{
  "code": "balance",
  "currency": "ILS",
  "percentage": 1,
  "totalWorth": 150000,
  "totalYieldPer": 0,
  "items": [{
    "name": "בנק של עומרי",
    "currency": "NIS",
    "worth": 150000,
    "portfolioPer": 1,
    "yield": 0,
    "yieldPer": 0
  }]
}, {
  "code": "debt",
  "currency": "ILS",
  "percentage": 1,
  "totalWorth": 150000,
  "totalYieldPer": 0,
  "items": [{
    "name": "משכנתא על הדירה שלי",
    "currency": "ILS",
    "worth": 150000,
    "portfolioPer": 1,
    "yield": 0,
    "yieldPer": 0
  }]
}, {
  "code": "pension",
  "currency": "ILS",
  "percentage": 1,
  "totalWorth": 150000,
  "totalYieldPer": 0,
  "items": [{
    "name": "פנסיוני",
    "currency": "ILS",
    "worth": 150000,
    "portfolioPer": 1,
    "yield": 0,
    "yieldPer": 0
  }]
}]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter ?

Comment: Can you be bit what's the correct expected output.

Comment: you can use, an object containing objects

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding, this solution would suffice:

```js
var resObj = {};
products.forEach((item) => {
  resObj[item.code] = item;
});

console.log(resObj);
```